# Refresh shared preferences after manual edit?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In may application, I am trying to allow the user to edit my sharedpreferences file directly with a text editor. Since the file can only be accessed on rooted phones, I have found a way to copy the file out to the SD card, allow the user to edit that file, then copy it back. This much works fine.

However, the app still uses the old values that were in the file prior to the change. The only way I can get it to load in the new values is to Force Stop the app and restart it.
I'm assuming Android is storing those values in a buffer somewhere. Is there any way to get it to update that buffer with the new values?

I've tried editor.commit(), getSharedPreferences, tried programmatically clearing cache and data. Not sure where to go from here... help!

Comment: You should post the code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make it so complicated?

create an Activity with all you properties you have in your SharedPreferences file and put in the current values of these prefs.

then the user can edit those values and you save it back this way no rooted phone needed

Comment: Because some of the properties are going to be very long strings that will be very easy to type in incorrectly and will be much easier for the user to create them in a text editor and then copy them into a file. An example of what one of these strings might look like is: "34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,34,3,45". I appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: If I can't get this to work, I will probably do exactly what you suggest and recommend that the user find a text editor app to cut/paste the data. I think it would be more elegant if I can get this to work.